# Making a TextBox PlaceholderText wrap

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-runtime, uwp

This question [has been asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27623611/windows-store-app-making-a-textbox-placeholder-wrap) already but thus far no answer. I find the TextBox `PlaceholderText` really useful as an indicator of some status info prior to text entry but the default non-wrap limits this useful feature.

Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will assume you are developing a Windows 10 (WinRT) app.
You need to create a new style for your `TextBox` and edit the element that displays the placeholder text (in this case it is the `CotentControl` with the name `PlaceholderTextContentPresenter`):

```
<TextBox PlaceholderText="Long text that needs to wrap">
    <TextBox.Style>
        <!--  Default style for Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextBox  -->
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlThemeMinWidth}" />
            <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlThemeMinHeight}" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundAltHighBrush}" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundChromeDisabledLowBrush}" />
            <Setter Property="SelectionHighlightColor" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAccentBrush}" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBorderThemeThickness}" />
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}" />
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden" />
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden" />
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled" Value="False" />
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlThemePadding}" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.Resources>
                                <Style x:Name="DeleteButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
                                    <Setter Property="Template">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                                <Grid
                                                    x:Name="ButtonLayoutGrid"
                                                    Background="{ThemeResource TextBoxButtonBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                                                    BorderBrush="{ThemeResource TextBoxButtonBorderThemeBrush}"
                                                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                                                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                                                <Storyboard>
                                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="GlyphElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAccentBrush}" />
                                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                </Storyboard>
                                                            </VisualState>
                                                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                                                <Storyboard>
                                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonLayoutGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAccentBrush}" />
                                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="GlyphElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltChromeWhiteBrush}" />
                                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                </Storyboard>
                                                            </VisualState>
                                                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                                                <Storyboard>
                                                                    <DoubleAnimation
                                                                        Duration="0"
                                                                        Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonLayoutGrid"
                                                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                                        To="0" />
                                                                </Storyboard>
                                                            </VisualState>
                                                        </VisualStateGroup>
                                                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                                    <TextBlock
                                                        x:Name="GlyphElement"
                                                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                        AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"
                                                        FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}"
                                                        FontSize="12"
                                                        FontStyle="Normal"
                                                        Foreground="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundChromeBlackMediumBrush}"
                                                        Text="&#xE10A;" />
                                                </Grid>
                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </Style>
                            </Grid.Resources>
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HeaderContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseLowBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledTransparentBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseLowBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseLowBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledChromeDisabledLowBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledChromeDisabledLowBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                    <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightChromeAltLowBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBackgroundHoverOpacity}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlPageTextChromeBlackMediumLowBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundChromeWhiteBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBackgroundFocusedOpacity}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAccentBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundChromeBlackHighBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RequestedTheme">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Light" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ButtonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="ButtonVisible">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="DeleteButton" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="ButtonCollapsed" />
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Border
                                x:Name="BackgroundElement"
                                Grid.Row="1"
                                Grid.RowSpan="1"
                                Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                Opacity="{ThemeResource TextControlBackgroundRestOpacity}" />
                            <Border
                                x:Name="BorderElement"
                                Grid.Row="1"
                                Grid.RowSpan="1"
                                Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" />
                            <ContentPresenter
                                x:Name="HeaderContentPresenter"
                                Grid.Row="0"
                                Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                Margin="0,0,0,8"
                                Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"
                                ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}"
                                FontWeight="Normal"
                                Foreground="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}"
                                Visibility="Collapsed"
                                x:DeferLoadStrategy="Lazy" />
                            <ScrollViewer
                                x:Name="ContentElement"
                                Grid.Row="1"
                                Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"
                                HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"
                                HorizontalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode}"
                                IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled}"
                                IsHorizontalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled}"
                                IsTabStop="False"
                                IsVerticalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled}"
                                Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}"
                                VerticalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode}"
                                ZoomMode="Disabled" />
                            <ContentControl
                                x:Name="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter"
                                Grid.Row="1"
                                Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                Foreground="{ThemeResource SystemControlPageTextBaseMediumBrush}"
                                IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                IsTabStop="False"
                                Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" >
                                <ContentControl.Content>
                                    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{TemplateBinding PlaceholderText}"/>
                                </ContentControl.Content>
                            </ContentControl>
                            <Button
                                x:Name="DeleteButton"
                                Grid.Row="1"
                                Grid.Column="1"
                                MinWidth="34"
                                Margin="{ThemeResource HelperButtonThemePadding}"
                                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"
                                IsTabStop="False"
                                Style="{StaticResource DeleteButtonStyle}"
                                Visibility="Collapsed" />
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

I have changed the `Content` property to be a `TextBlock` with the `TextWrapping` property set.

For other platforms this is basically the same, you just need to edit the default style of the `TextBox` control. You can generate those either in Visual Studio itself (in XAML designer view -> right click -> Edit Templates ...), or find it on the internet.

Comment: Thank you. I note that you change
 `Content="{TemplateBinding PlaceholderText}"` 

to

    <ContentControl.Content>
       <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
    </ContentControl.Content>

which does the trick.

However the line `<TextBlock Text="{Binding}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
    </ContentControl.Content>` should be `<TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding PlaceholderText}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />`

Could you correct your XAML so that I can mark as answered.

Comment: I have edited my answer. I was too rash. I am happy to have helped you out.

Comment: Marked as answered.
Also worth remarking that it's a good idea to define a Style on its own (convenient to tuck away in a common Style file), for instance:

`<Style x:Key="WrappingPlaceholderTextStyle" TargetType="TextBox">`

and use a Style attribute on TextBox rather than use both TextBox and Style XAML together. I am sure developers can figure this out but a minor point. Thanks again.